# can browsers select scripts based on user's viewing resolution?

Tags: resolution

I want to implement a JQuery script that requires the browser's width at 100% which depends solely on the user's viewing resolution. Can i prepare multiple scripts for the different resolutions for the browser to automatically detect and choose or does there need to be a single script with if/then clauses?

Answer (score 0):

[Apparently the can via Javascript](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/browser-screen-resolution/) using screen.width and screen.height.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know what exactly you are trying to implement, you might want to look into CSS media queries as an interesting approach to adaptive Layouts.